# Google Cloud Storage Bucket in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, double-click-advertising

I'm trying to access a bucket on our Google Cloud Storage.

On my login details, I don't have permissions to open the bucket. How do I add another user to use on the `gcloud` console using a JSON token?

[image: Screenshot for reference]

I know the bucket was actually setup by Google. It's a data dump from DoubleClick. Want to pull the data down with BigQuery, but I can't see any of the datasets or run any queries against it with my current level of access.

Would this be something I can set myself using the token provided by Google or must I get hold of them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bucket where Google dump the data transfer logs is owned by them. It's administrated through a private Google group, and they need to add your email (or service account email) for access. To get access to need to reach out to your Google DFP rep.

However, you should consider using the direct DFP data transfer service, instead of hand rolling your own DFP->GCS->BigQuery pipelines. Google will dump your DFP data transfer logs directly into BigQuery for you. So, there's no need to muck around with GCS.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-service-overview

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm in touch with the right people at DoubleClick now. Progress :)

Comment: Awesome. We've written a few blogs about our journey of DFP logs + BigQuery. Some good nuggets of info in here --> https://shinesolutions.com/2014/01/18/reeling-in-big-data-using-googles-bigquery/

Comment: Very cool article. I'm actually sitting on a similar, but much smaller, a project I need to rework soon. Using BigQuery might be a great option.